# Autofac How to specify the constructor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using Autofac for dependency injection.

I have below codes in application start.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterType(typeof(HolidayService)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

I have MVC controller as follows

```
public class MyController : Controller{
    private IHolidayService _HolidayService;    

    public MyController (IHolidayService holidayService) {
        //I want this constructor to be called**
        this._HolidayService = holidayService;
    }

    private MyController () {
        //but this constructor is called unfortunately

    } 
}
```

I want the parameterized constructor to be called. But it call the default constructor.

What should I do to call the the parameterized constructor ?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that your code in Application_Start is called ?

Comment: Why do you need default constructor? Could you delete the default constructor and debug again?

Comment: if we don't have the default constructor it gives error that I don't have a default constructor

Comment: Why do you have the second constructor in the first place? You components should have [just one constructor](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the stack trace of the error without the default constructor. It looks like MVC is not configured to use Autofac.

Comment: "like MVC is not configured to use Autofac" what does this mean?

Comment: I am facing this issue when I call a method as ajax from client side

Comment: Can you post the `HolidayService` class signature? If Autofac is trying to use the parameterless constructor it's because it doesn't think an `IHolidayService` is registered.